# bundleForClass not returning framework bundle iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

Using **bundleForClass** for retrieving bundle of framework where i have defined a class.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle **bundleForClass**: [self class]]; // Class in framework

NSString *readtext = [bundle **pathForResource**:@"Test" ofType:@"rtf"];
```

Getting appbundle of application(Where i am using my framework) instead of framework bundle.

How to get **framework bundle path** and read the framework resources.

Comment: As per the Apple Documentation of NSBundle Return value -The NSBundle object that dynamically loaded aClass (a loadable bundle), the NSBundle object for the framework in which aClass is defined, or the main bundle object if aClass was not dynamically loaded or is not defined in a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load NSBundle with Bundle Identifier of framework:

```
[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:YOUR_FRAMEWORK_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIRE];
```

If the framework has a resources bundle in it, then you can access the resources by:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[YOUR_CLASS_NAME class]];
NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:RESOURCE_BUNDLE_NAME withExtension:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:url];
UIImage* infoImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[resourceBundle pathForResource:@"info" ofType:@"png"]];
```

Comment: can we edit txt file in framework resource dynamically?

Comment: you can't edit that file, but can make a copy to document directory of this file  and can make changes in it.